# Need help with writing "perpendicular"

Tags: math-mode, symbols

I am new to LaTeX and am writing in overleaf with other students, however, I cannot figure out how I format "a perpendicular" like so: `a⊥`. I tried doing `\(\a\perp\)`, but the document will only display `a`, not the `⊥` symbol, anyone know how to add this? I saw on that I might need to import `amssymb`, however, I don't know how to do this either and I can't find a solution.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Actually, you should be able to get what you want by entering `\(a\perp\)` without loading any packages. Could you perhaps post a compilable minimal example of what you have?

Comment: As mentioned we need a minimal self contained example so we can see what exactly you are doing. It would also be useful to know how exactly you are viewing the result.